# Page object model is not Working Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

My Selenium python code for POM is Not Working Properly guys i dunno what Wrong i did down am Pasting My Code Please Sort Me Out.

**index.py**

the Location is = `MyProject/Testmethods/index.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



class Wepaythemaxindex(object):
    def Locators(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.fname = "//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_fname']"
        self.lname = "//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_lname']"
        self.contact = "//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_phone']"
        self.email = "//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_email']"
        self.Location = "//select[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_drp_pref_loc']"
        self.findus = "//select[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSource']"
        self.clicknext = "//a[@id='inner-submit_next']"
        self.year ="//select[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_Drp_Year']"
        self.make ="//select[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_drp_Carname']"
        self.textyear ="//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_Drp_Year1']"
        self.textmake = "//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_drp_Carname1']"
        self.getstarted = "//a[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_vehicle_info_next']"
        self.header ="//span[@class='cd-words-wrapper']"
        self.content = '.paragraphs > .row '




    def checkchromedriver(self):
        print("---------Welcome to XXXXXXXXXX-----------")
        print("-------MainForm------------")
        self.UpdateLeadForm(self.driver)
        print("-------SideForm------------")
        self.SideForm(self.driver)



    def UpdateLeadForm(self,driver):

     box=["1","2","3","4","5"]
     for button in box:
        # Clicking on the car
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[1]/li[" +str(button)+ "]/a[1]/span[1]").click()

        # Waiting for 10seconds
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        self.lead(driver)


    def SideForm(self,driver):
        form=["1","2","3","4","5"]
        for clickform in form:
            self.Scrolldown(driver)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/ul[2]/li[" +str(clickform)+ "]/a[1]/span[1]").click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            self.lead(driver)

    def Scrolldown(self,driver):
        SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

        # Get scroll height
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        while True:
            # Scroll down to bottom
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            last_height = new_height

    def lead(self,driver):
        # Typing the fname
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.fname)
        elem.send_keys("test")

        # Typing the Lname
        elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.lname)
        elem2.send_keys("test")

        # Typing the contact
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.contact).send_keys("9176300256")

        # Typing the email
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.email).send_keys("koushick@rcktechiees.com")

        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.Location))
        select.select_by_index(2)

        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("C:\\Users\\rck\\PycharmProjects\\Wepaythemax\\Screenshot\\Wepaythemax.png")

        select1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.findus))
        select1.select_by_visible_text("SIGNAGE")

        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.clicknext)
        elem.click()

        year = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.year)
        try:
         if year.is_displayed():
            selectyear = Select(year)
            selectyear.select_by_index(15)
            print("element is Selected")
         else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.textyear).send_keys("2016")
        except ElementNotVisibleException:
            print(ElementNotVisibleException)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print(NoSuchElementException)


        make = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.make)

        try:
         if make.is_displayed():
            selectmake = Select(make)
            selectmake.select_by_visible_text("HONDA")
            print("Make is Selected")
         else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.textmake).send_keys("Test")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print(NoSuchElementException)
        except ElementNotVisibleException:
            print(ElementNotVisibleException)

        Getstarted = driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.getstarted)
        Getstarted.click()

        driver.implicitly_wait(15)

        assert "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/Thank_you.aspx" in driver.current_url
        print("Lead Updated Succesfully!")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(
            "C:\\Users\\rck\\PycharmProjects\\Wepaythemax\\Screenshot\\Wepaythemaxthankyou.png")
        driver.get("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/")
```

the Above code i have written is for index page, i need to access it in final test case page so i have done like this below,

FinalTest.py

Location: `Myproject/Testcase/FinalTest.py`

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from TestMethods.index import Wepaythemaxindex

class Wepaythemax(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driverchrome = webdriver.Chrome("F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe")


    def test_Pages(self):
        driver = self.driverchrome
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/")
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        for text_node in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.cd-words-wrapper > b'):
            print(text_node.get_attribute('textContent'))
        index = Wepaythemaxindex()
        index.checkchromedriver()






    def tearDown(self):
        self.driverchrome.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()



The output is : It's Opening the Browser, Works Till text_node, when it comes to accessing the object of index page, it throwing different different error.
```

**In java i have cleared so many critical issues i have faced. but as new to python i can't find any clear material to figure this out.**

Comment: Which command operation is giving you the error? Then maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: am getting error in line index = Wepaythemaxindex(driver)
TypeError: Wepaythemaxindex() takes no arguments @LuisEstevez

Comment: Yes it doesn't take arguments. you didn't implement a constructor.
`def __init__(self, arg):`
    `self.someArg = arg`

Comment: @LuisEstevez Thank God! it Worked . i removed my [def Locators] and Pasted under [def __init__(self,driver)] and i called that page in the final test. The Magic happened .

Comment: Perfect! Adding an official answer then. If you could be kind to mark as approved answer :)

Comment: if my question is useful, don't forget to upvote it. Thanks! @LuisEstevez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't implement a constructor. For example:

```
def __init__(self, arg):
    self.someArg = arg
```